# Why only the servername for the DB connection?

Tags: sql-server, server, database-connection, connection-string, sql-server-2017

Just installed SQL Server 2017 Enterprise Evaluation on a Windows 2012 R2 evaluation, fully updated everything.

The machine name is: SQLTEST
The Instance Id is: SQLTESTDB

DB Is on separate machine in all tests.

When I connect via a .Net app I can only connect if I just use SQLTEST in the connectionstring.

If I connect via Management studio 2008 R2 or version 18.3.1 (the very latest); If I search network it only shows me SQLTEST i.e. SERVERNAME and not SERVERNAME\INSTANCENAME like it does for about 4 other database machines that are on the network.

From my research this is not normal, and I can't find anyone who has experienced the same!

Is this 'wrong'? If so why is it working or more importantly how to 'correct it' as it seems odd to not specify the DB Instance Id.

**EDIT:** This command does not work:

> sqlcmd -S SQLTEST\SQLTESTDB

I get the following error:

```
SqlCmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF].
SqlCmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
SqlCmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
```

**EDIT 2**: Think I'm onto something, I gave it an Instance Id of 'SQLTESTDB' but left it as a 'Default Instance' (which I understood to 'usually' be the machine name... hmm somethings wrong in my thinking and understanding here.

It seems that I don't know what the hell giving it an 'Instance Id' of SQLTESTDB did, leaving it as 'Default Instance' during installation has named it MSSQLSERVER.

However

> SQLTEST\MSSQLSERVER does not work either?!?!?!?

Comment: Might `SQLTEST` have 2 instances installed, and the `SQLTESTDB` instance doesn't have the browser enabled?

Comment: Try using `sqlcmd -S SQLTEST\SQLTESTDB` . Does that work?

Comment: Looks like sqlcmd cannot find the server, or at least not port 1433 on the server.  Can you ping it from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that SQL Server 2017 either has a different way' of installing instances than I've encountered on SQL Server 2008 R2, 2005 etc.

The reason it was using just a machine name for connections seems to be linked to my using a Default Instance (I also gave it an 'Instance Id' of SQLTESTDB), which by the way resulted in the instance being named 'MSSQLSERVER', although it could not be connected to using SQLTEST/MSSQLSERVER.

So the default instance used just the machine name, any other instances that I installed on that machine would have to be named.

I uninstalled and reinstalled SQL SERVER and this time gave it an Instance Name of SQLTESTDB and everything was as expected, i.e. I now connect to the DB using SQLTEST\SQLTESTDB.